# combining byte arrays to pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, pdf

I've a byte array which I get from an API.

```
byte[] sticker = db.call_API_print_sticker(Id);
```

I have to call this method a number of times and then convert to pdf.  I want to store it in an array of arrays and then convert them once I have all them

How do I store it and then combine the byte array pdfs to one.

Answer (score 7):

Using PDFSharp as a Nuget, I wrote the following C# method that purely works with byte arrays:

```
    public byte[] CombinePDFs(List<byte[]> srcPDFs)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var resultPDF = new PdfDocument(ms))
            {
                foreach (var pdf in srcPDFs)
                {
                    using (var src = new MemoryStream(pdf))
                    {
                        using (var srcPDF = PdfReader.Open(src, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
                        {
                            for (var i = 0; i < srcPDF.PageCount; i++)
                            {
                                resultPDF.AddPage(srcPDF.Pages[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                resultPDF.Save(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

So the above method takes an array list of source PDFs and combine them and returns a single byte array for the result PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The `byte[]` is just one pdf probably. I would think that you could just do

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"sticker.pdf", sticker);
```

If that is not the case, the easiest way would be to use a nuget package [ex: PdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to combine multiple pdfs into one.

[An example of combining pdfs](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=34&Itemid=45)

The gist (which assumes each sticker contains 1 page):

```
IEnumerable<byte[]> stickers;
using (var combinedPdf = new PdfDocument(@"stickers.pdf"))
foreach (var pdf in stickers)
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdf))
{
    var someSticker = PdfReader.Open(ms);
    combinedPdf.AddPage(someSticker.Pages[0]);
}
```